# mysql_fetch_array, seemingly not returning value

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I have a result from an SQL query in $result,

```
$result = $query->fetchall((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

It looks like this on a var dump:

```
  array(7) {
    ["index"]=>
    string(2) "59"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(32) "154FA6BFDFAA3B283452E84DCC41AF1D"
    ["trigger_price"]=>
    string(2) "33"
    ["currency"]=>
    string(1) "$"
    ["direction"]=>
    string(1) ">"
    ["title"]=>
    string(1) "T"
    ["date_set"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-09 07:21:17"
  }
```

When I then try to loop through to access an element of the result set nothing is printed. I'm using this code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    echo $row["title"];
}
```

I'm finding so many stumbling blocks in PHP it's driving me insane, it's like there is 10 ways to do everything, but only one of them seems to ever work!!

I'm using MAMP so maybe the syntax is slightly different, correct answer to anyone who can help.

I also tried:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
```

and:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo $row;
}
```

Comment: Your irst line is using PDO to fetch data, whilst later you're using `mysql_fectch_array`. PDO and `mysql` are different extensions to PHP, and while they do a similar job you can't mix them. Use the PDO versions.

Comment: Oh, thanks Mike that's helpful, sorry i'm a PHP beginner and it's really quite messy for me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I've already fetchedall into a variable using this: $result = $query->fetchall((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));   How can I then access each row from that array?

Comment: Tip: read the manual. `PDOStatement::fetchAll` defines that it returns an array. `mysql_fetch_*` defines that it needs a mysql result resource. You obviously can't mix those.

Comment: Why don't they deprecate mysql_fetch when they now have pdo, it only serves to confuse!

Comment: They did! There's a large red box *in the manual* and the latest PHP version officially throws deprecation notices. BTW, that's where your downvote comes from: you obviously did not read the manual. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` you can iterate over the array using a simple foreach:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo $row["title"];
}
```

Alternatively, instead of using `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` you can use `PDOStatement::fetch()`, which is roughly the equivalent of `mysql_fetch_array()`:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row["title"];
}
```

The `mysql_*` functions cannot be interchanged with PDO and they are deprecated and discouraged.

Comment: Thanks alot @MrCode, I don't know why whenever I ask a PHP question I get down voted, people have to learn from somewhere! and in my opinion it's alot more convoluted than ObjC/C++

Comment: No problem :). Anything that asks about `mysql_*` tends to get downvoted because that library has been deprecated for years. The wider problem is so many bad online PHP tutorials and articles still teaching using that lib.